# Какую структуру использовать для построения точек на лице?

Tags: python, машинное-обучение

есть выборка из 300 фотографий (это с учётом аугментации, больше не получилось выжать) изображений лиц и 300 этих же лиц, только с отмеченными опорными точками
Задача научить машину находить эти самые точки на любом лице
Не было в этом опыта, но очевидно дело за сверткой, только вот как грамотно построить процесс и обучить машину?